# Google Cloud Pub/Sub Publisher Lifecycle

Tags: asp.net, singleton, google-cloud-pubsub, azure-load-balancer, quartz.net-3.0

I'm running a Cloud Pub/Sub `PublisherClient` instance as a `Singleton` in an ASP.NET web application (.NET Standard 2). Does this retain a persistent HTTPS connection to the specified Cloud Pub/Sub Topic and should I call the `ShutdownAsync` method explicitly, or just let the connection be severed when the app pool recycles?

Running this in conjunction with Quartz.NET, publishing messages to Pub/Sub in relatively small batches, every 30 seconds. This seems to introduce server affinity  in a 3-node Azure Load Balancer cluster, where the majority of traffic is routed to any given node after running for 1+ hours. Not 100% sure about best practices here.

Using Pub/Sub C# NuGet package V1 1.0 and Quartz NuGet 3.0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you’re using [this PublisherClient](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.PublisherClient.html). Per the [sample documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/#sample-code), the PublisherClient instance should be shut down after use. This ensures that locally queued messages get sent. See also the [ShutdownAsync documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.PublisherClient.html#Google_Cloud_PubSub_V1_PublisherClient_ShutdownAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

Comment: Yes, exactly that. The `PublisherClient`runs in the context of a web application, publishing messages throughout the lifetime of the application. Would rather not shutdown after each publish operation if I can help it

Comment: Can you arrange for `ShutdownAsync` to be called when the application shuts down?

Comment: Yes, that's the current implementation. Wondering if it's best practice. Presume it's OK to use `PublisherClient` in a static manner, similar to `HttpClient`

Comment: Is there anything specific about the Pub/Sub SDK, or Quartz.NET that might cause server affinity in a 3-node load-balanced cluster?

Comment: `Yes, that's the current implementation. Wondering if it's best practice`

That seems in line with the documentation.

`Is there anything specific about the Pub/Sub SDK, or Quartz.NET that might cause server affinity in a 3-node load-balanced cluster`

That seems like another question and requires more background. Feel free to ask it as a new question.